# ApolloClient: Invariant Violation 1 – setup apollo client properly

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

I am new to GraphQL and Apollo and I am really struggling with setting up an apolloClient in node.js.

First I want to mention that I sucessfully set up an apollo client within nuxt using [nuxt's apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module).

So I am completely sure that my endpoint and my token are working.

Now I wanted to setup an apollo client within a JavaScript file, which I want to run in node.js.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'

export default function generateRoutesFromData(
  options = {
    api: [],
    query: '',
    token: '',
    bundle: '',
    homeSlug: 'home',
    errorPrefix: 'error-'
  }
) {
  const uri = 'https://example.com/api'
  const token =
    '...fPsvYqkheQXXmlWgb...'

  const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri, fetch })

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  })

  const GET_PAGES = gql`
    {
      helloWorld
    }
  `

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    fetch
  })

  client
    .query({
      query: GET_PAGES
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log('result: ', result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error: ', error)
    })

  // for now just return array with a test string
  // later on: return all uris fetched via graphql
  return ['/test']
}
```

If I run this in node I get the following error:

> FATAL  Invariant Violation: 1 (see https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)                                                                                00:05:36
>
> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: 1 (see https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)
>
> at new InvariantError (packages/.../node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.js:16:28)
>
> at new ApolloClient (packages/.../node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2483:55)
>
> at generateRoutesFromData (packages/.../src/routes/generateRoutesFromData.js:41:18)
>     at Object. (nuxt.config.js:158:10)
>     at Generator.next ()

I googled for about 1.5h and did not make any progress...
The error message is very cryptic and I don't know what I could do.

I must say the whole documentation arount apollo is pretty confusing.
Apollo-boost and which wraps apollo client all other stuff. Different ways of authenticating etc.

I found this page:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration/
But it seems quite complex and I am not sure, if this will even help me with anything...

Any help with this is much appreciated!
Cheers
m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your client configuration is missing a `cache`:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(), // <-- ADD ME
})
```

This is the [actual error](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/7eaf4132cd2cd6244260777799406aaa03fcf377/packages/apollo-client/src/ApolloClient.ts#L139) you're seeing:

> In order to initialize Apollo Client, you must specify 'link' and 'cache' properties in the options object.
>   These options are part of the upgrade requirements when migrating from Apollo Client 1.x to Apollo Client 2.x.
>   For more information, please visit: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client.html#apollo-client-setup

Invariant errors are intentionally obfuscated in production. I'm not sure why you would be seeing that behavior locally but maybe Nuxt is setting `NODE_ENV` to `production` at some point before that code evaluates.

Comment: Thank you. I assume that the nuxt env is not available at that point, so maybe that's the cause...